# Perform action on selection of UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to call a function when a cell is pressed and I would like to be able to change what that function does based on what cell is pressed. Here is my code currently:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 4
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(90, 90)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 10
}


// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate


// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}



// Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}



// Uncomment these methods to specify if an action menu should be displayed for the specified item, and react to actions performed on the item
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.printThatItWorked()
}

func printThatItWorked()
{
    println("It worked")
}
```

the function `printThatItWorked()` should be called whenever a cell is selected, and eventually I would like to be able to have it print that cell number x was pressed. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The delegate method `didSelectCell...` is where you want to put that code.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // You can use indexPath to get "cell number x", or get the cell like:
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    printThatItWorked()
}
```

Comment: When I paste this into my file I get the error: "UICollectionView does not have a member named cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: Oops. The method signature is `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Item, not Row. Updated my answer.

Comment: I have updated the code in my file to this. It is still not calling that function.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the didSelectCell method. Does it hit that breakpoint when you select a cell? Are the cells/collection view select enabled? Are any of the other delegate calls being called? Are you the delegate for the collection view?

Comment: I figured it out. Please see my answer to this question.

Comment: I see. Added `override` to my answer.

Comment: override was not the issue. You need to change `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Implement this:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // You can use indexPath to get "cell number x", or get the cell like:
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    printThatItWorked()
}
```